# Spring Stomp websockets with activemq client

Tags: spring, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying to build a stomp websocket and use amazon activemq service.

it provides 2 url (one in case of failure) and I was wondering if I could use the ActiveMQConnectionFactory to setup  the message broker.

so, basically inside `DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration` use `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` to set the client on the `stompBroker`, instead of or along the ReactorNettyTcpClient.

Basicaly I want to take advantage of the failure recovery url in aws mq.